# Sanity Init Gives authentdication Error #4058

Tags: sanity

I want to create a backend using sanity. I have installed sanity CLI using the command 'npm install -g @sanity/cli'. After that, I create a project using the command sanity init. But It gives the following error when authenticating. But my google account and sanity account are already logged in.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWS2K.png)

Comment: This could be a PATH issue. Although this link isn't related to Sanity, could you please try the suggestion [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1818#issuecomment-573710218)?

Answer (score 0):

add C:\Windows\System32 to your path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your windows Environmental Variables add C:\Windows\System32\ to the PATH variable in System Variables.

I had the same issue and this fixed it.